# Navigation Bar No Longer Showing from Storyboard in Controller - Swift (Updated View Controller To Handle Opening Links WEBVIEW)

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, swiftui-navigationview

With the following code, I was able to display my Navigation Bar build on Storyboard, however, andy URL links would not open and were dead. I found my ViewController needed a way to handle using a decision handler. (SEE WHAT DID I TRY SECTION)

import UIKit
import WebKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController  {

```
        @IBOutlet weak var webViewTwo: WKWebView!
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            

            
            let url = URL(string: "https://on.sprintful.com/dr-clutter-junk")
            webViewTwo.load(URLRequest(url: url!))
                  
        }
        
        override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
            return .lightContent
        }
```

}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBj5i.png)

**SECTION: WHAT DID I TRY**

With the following code, the links work but the Nav Bar from StoryBoard does not display.
I believe the is the IB Outlet reference is the issue. When I go to edit the

"func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler:" and alter it to "func webViewTwo(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler:" the nav bar wont show and links do not work.

import UIKit
import WebKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
@IBOutlet var webViewTwo: WKWebView!

```
override func loadView() {
    webViewTwo = WKWebView()
    view = webViewTwo
    let url = URL(string: "https://calendly.com/drclutterjunk")!
    webViewTwo.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    webViewTwo.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    webViewTwo.navigationDelegate = self
    
    
}
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
            if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated  {
                if let url = navigationAction.request.url,
                let host = url.host, host.hasPrefix("dttps://calendly.com") !=
                    UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                        decisionHandler(.cancel)
                } else {
                    // Open in web view
                    decisionHandler(.allow)
                }
            } else {
                // other navigation type, such as reload, back or forward buttons
                decisionHandler(.allow)
            }
        }

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .darkContent
}


}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXWxb.png)